# Camel bean-validator with group validation doesn't start for FailedToStartRouteException

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, apache-camel, bean-validation

I'm trying to use the camel-bean-validator dependency in my project but I have a problem with group validation.
I'm using a springboot project with spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.3 and these dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-bean-validator-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My SimpleDto is:

```
@Data
public class SimpleDto {

    @NotNull(groups = BasicValidation.class)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(groups = AdvancedValidation.class)
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String value;

}
```

And I created two interfaces for validation:

```
    public interface AdvancedValidation {
    }
```

```
    public interface AdvancedValidation {
    }
```

When I want to use a standard validation like this in my route the application starts without problem:

```
@Component
public class ValidationRoute extends RouteBuilder {


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("timer:val-timer?period=5000")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    SimpleDto simpleDto = new SimpleDto();
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(simpleDto);
                }
            })
            .log("Setted body: ${body}")
            .to("bean-validator://x")
            .log("Validated message");
    }
}
```

but when I change the validation endpoint in:

```
.to("bean-validator://x?group=AdvancedValidation")
```

like in the example in Apache Camel documentation, here:

https://camel.netlify.app/components/latest/bean-validator-component.html

the application stop working and this is the error I have starting it:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3365)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:3033)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2988)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2649)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at it.ale.CamelArchetypeTestApplication.main(CamelArchetypeTestApplication.java:16)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AdvancedValidation
    at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeException(RuntimeCamelException.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.doFail(BaseService.java:413)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.fail(BaseService.java:342)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:132)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1670)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:126)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doStart(Pipeline.java:224)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.startChildServices(RouteService.java:396)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:193)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:121)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AdvancedValidation
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultClassResolver.resolveMandatoryClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.validator.BeanValidatorEndpoint.createProducer(BeanValidatorEndpoint.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.createAsyncProducer(DefaultEndpoint.java:200)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:242)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    ... 44 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I already tried to change the endpoint with:

```
.to("bean-validator://x?group=AdvancedValidation.class")
```

and this time the error was:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AdvancedValidation.class
```

Also adding the annotation @Component to the interface I haven't solved the problem.

Does anyone know why it is not working and how to solve it?
I followed the documentation and there it seem work.

Using the same interfaces and the same project in a RestController and validating it with @Valid or @Validated(AdvancedValidation.class) worked correctly, so this is a Camel issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably solved it by using all the class path related to group:

```
.to("bean-validator://x?group=com.application.dto.validation.group.AdvancedValidation")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, this finally worked correctly! Thanks!